# how to use Bazel to test the performance of GRPC++?

Tags: c++, grpc

Now I get GRPC from https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git, and want to use the Performance Testing in the path of `./test/cpp/qps` to get the performance of GRPC++.

`root#bazel build :test/cpp/qps`

I have gotten the Files compiled by Bazel, but I can't get the way to use it. Because the number of files in `./Bazel-bin` is too much to analyze for a new person like me.

Can someone help me out here? Make it well to test or just telling me how to use it, is good for me.

Comment: thanks for editing to correct my grammatical errors.I'm not a English native speaker.

Comment: When you use `bazel build` command and built a binary target successfully, at the end of the output it'll show you the location of the artifact. It's likely in the /bazel-bin directory in your workspace.

Comment: I don't see any path of output but the debug infomation,I know it should run in `./bazel-bin` and how to find  the server `qps_worker`,but the client have a big number in it and I  don't know which is needed in my assumption of 32 threads and 100 outstanding_rpcs and streaming which is set in Java.